# Command button on sub form turns grey (but is active)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, commandbutton, subform

I have a sub form that contains a command button with some custom theme (blue color) but whenever I switch from design view(main form) to the form view, the cmd button on sub form turns grey (some sort of an old fashioned button but is still active). Then, if I close the entire form and reopen, its fine now. The problem is occurring only when I switch from design view to form view(without closing the entire form and reopening it).

I am using Access 2013.

Comment: Not sure why it changes it when you flip-flop, but you could always set the background color in the load or activate event. 2007 had a bug where it randomly changed some textbox backgrounds to grey...

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Thanks for the reply but the idea (setting backcolor on load) as you mentioned didn't work for me. The problem doesn't occur on 2010 access but does occur on 2013 access. Seems like a bug on 2013 or might be I am missing something here.

Comment: Hi,I have faced a similar issue. It seems quite likely to be a bug. I found that recreating the button in Acccess 2013 solves the problem.

Comment: @izzymo that didn't help either :(